# Can I get EXPLAIN ANALYZE output through the lib/pq Go SQL driver?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I'd like to be able to evaluate my queries inside my app, which is in Go and using the github.com/lib/pq driver.  Unfortunately, neither the [lib/pq docs][1] nor the [database/sql][2] docs seem to say anything about this, and nothing in the database/sql interfaces suggests this is possible.

Has anyone found a way to get this output?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Go driver so I'm not aware of idiosyncrasies there, but explain/explain analyze output looks just like select output - you get back tabular data that is one column wide and has one row per query plan step, so you should be able to use your regular row iteration methods to process the explain results equivalently to how you'd process any select statement results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typical `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` returns several rows, so you can do it with simple `sql.Query`. Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=test dbname=test sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY slug")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        var s string
        if err := rows.Scan(&s); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```